# Extract data from public Tableau dashboard

Tags: python, web-scraping, tableau-api

I'm trying to get data from a public Tableau dashboard, but I'm not sure how to do it. I've looked around online and seen some suggestions for using the Tableau Server Client library in Python, but I'm not familiar with it.

The dashboard I'm interested in is located at [https://public.tableau.com/app/profile/pierre2770/viz/TotalCyberAttacks/Dashboard1]. I want to extract the data from the dashboard so I can use it in some data analysis I'm doing. I've tried to find a download or export option in the dashboard itself, but there doesn't seem to be one.

Could someone help me figure out how to use the Tableau Server Client library to get data from this dashboard? Or is there another way to do it that I'm not aware of?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,
Amine

Answer (score 0):

The manner in which this workbook was published has the permissions set so that downloading the workbook is disabled.  As such, obtaining the data itself isn't possible through the Tableau server (public or otherwise) interface, nor through any Tableau API.

Instead, you'll have to resort to one of two approaches:

1. Contact the author and kindly request that they share their data.  The author seems to come from this company -- https://www.hiscox.com/brokers/cyber.
2. Create a data scraping script that sorts through each combination of selections from the dashboard - Country (8), Size of Business(5), Industry(14), Maturity(3). (About 1680 rows of data would be expected).  The Tableau API could be useful here - there are various ones to choose from (see developer resources on this page -- https://www.tableau.com/support/help).